# SoundJS: Partial Preload

Tags: javascript, soundjs

I am developing a simple quiz game for fun. The player has to listen to a MP3 file and guess the associated game and/or character's name. Currently, I am preloading the whole audio file through SoundJS. The game can be tried here: http://simon.pcharest.ca/quiz/

What I would like to do is to preload and play only a 10 seconds audio clip, starting at a random position. This would make the loading much shorter and the game a bit harder too.

Is this something doable with SoundJS, and if so, could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createjs.Sound.play("MyAudioSprite", {startTime: 1000, duration: 400});

Source: http://www.createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/AudioSprite.html